# ESTA like travel authorizations

Tags: esta, eta

The US introduced ESTA, a visa like online travel authorization in 2008: [ESTA at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_System_for_Travel_Authorization).

Some other countries have introduced similar procedures e.g. Canada and Australia.  Others, e.g. the EU and the UK are planning similar procedures.

Was the US the first to do this?  Who else does?

Comment: While interesting historically, I'll note that the second entry on the [Travel Help Page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) of Expected Conduct is: You should only ask _practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face_." This question doesn't seem to reflect the existence of an actual travel problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't address an actual travel problem faced by the asker.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Sorry, I had not noticed that.

Comment: This _might_ be on-topic for [history.se]

Answer (score 2):

An answer based on a comment from GiacomoCatenazzi since the comments will be deleted soon.

This Wikipedia page answers my question: [Electronic visa @ Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_visa).

It appears that Australia was the first.

There are now many other countries using the system.  There are some technical differences between eVisa, ETA (Electronic Travel Authorisation), and EVW (Electronic Visa Waiver) but these are beyond the scope of this question.  Some countries may use more than one type depending on the applicant's nationality.  Also, which nationalities may use which type for which country is complex.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it appears that Australia was indeed the first to introduce electronic authorization but it was an improvement because prior to that *everyone* had to apply for a physical visa sticker in advance. The first country to introduce electronic authorization for formerly visa free nations was the U.S.

Comment: @JonathanReez Thanks, I'll add that in.

Comment: I think things like ETA and ESTA on the one hand are very different to things like eVisas (never heard of EVW before). The main one is that I believe they are much longer-term. A visa generally covers one trip or in the case of a multiple-entry visa limited to a small specific number of visas or to a period of time like 6 or 12 months. ETA and ESTA is either lifetime or numerous years. Please correct me if I have some misunderstandings though.

Comment: @hippietrail I'm not saying that they are the same, just that it is beyond this question.  I had not heard of EVW either until I read that article.  I have not heard of a life time ESTA / ETA.  US is 2 years and I think that Canada is as well.  The eVisa that I just got for India is 1 year.  I read once that the US did not want to call it a visa for a technical, legal reason.

Comment: Ah yes I was writing off the top of my head. I've only ever had one for Canada which I wasn't even visiting but transiting at the airport. I was totally wrong. Australia's is 1 year, Canada's is 5 years, and the US's is 2 years. More visa-ish than I believed.